# Subtracting two lists with indices in Python

Tags: python

I have two lists, `A1` and `A2` with indices. I want to find out `A1 - A2`. The desired output is attached.

```
A1= [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(2,1),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)]
A2= [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2)]
```

The desired output is

```
[(1,0),(1,1),(2,1),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)]
```

Comment: Could you provide your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this

```
A3 = [i for i in A1 if not i in A2]
print(A3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [list.remove](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

You can iterate in the list A2 and remove each element from A1:

```
A1= [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(2,1),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)]
A2= [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2)]

for idx in A2:
   A1.remove(idx)
print(A1)
```

and the output should be:

```
[(1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```